# Select row which atleast contains the search query

Tags: mysql, search

For each row I have a column which contains numbers like this `1,4,6,3,16,13`. How do I search for a row which contains atleast that number? Note that it shouldn't mislead `1` only from `11`, or `6` from `16` and so on.

---

```
SELECT FROM table WHERE category LIKE %$query$%
```

Table Structure:

```
id | title | category | description | rating
```

Comment: Please post your table structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, category) != 0
```

Where `1` is whatever number you're looking for.

Comment: great solution, just knew about `FIND_IN_SET` +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema and put category_id on a separate table.

To directly answer your question, try:

```
WHERE category LIKE "$query,%" OR category LIKE "%,$query,%";
```

To safeguard yourself from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) when using that, make sure $query contains only numbers by doing: `$query = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '', $query);`